# Can wget convert links within a local html document?

Tags: wget, mirroring

I know that wget can fetch a remote page and its dependencies and rewrite the html so that image `src` attributes reference the newly downloaded images.

I am trying to convert local html files that reference images on the Internet.
I'm using

```
wget --mirror --page-requisites --convert-links \
     --directory-prefix=foo \
     --force-html \
     --input-file=my_file.html
```

All of the referenced images are downloaded to the appropriate places in `foo/` but the `src` attributes in `my_file.html` aren't being changed.

Comment: That's a pretty neat use of wget.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
wget --recursive --page-requisites --convert-links --span-hosts http://localhost/some.html
```

Comment: This still requires that I run an http server on my local machine just for wget--is there no way to do this using --input-file?

Comment: I am afraid not. Wget do not support `file://` scheme. `--input-file` is only to read many urls conveniently in a batch manner.

Comment: Many of the images in the file have a relative `src`, so if I serve it from localhost wget 404's. Apparently the `--base` flag can only be used with `--input-file` and `--force-html`.

Comment: Can you serve also the images? Using symlinks you can link to a `foo/` directory with images, so your localhost path mimics that in relative `src` paths. Or you can edit html files and place `base` tag with appropriate `href` attribute in `<head>` section.